# Passing an SQL datasource variable in page load?

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have an SQL query but it will will only know the movie type in page load. This will be connected to a datalist.

My query is

```
select * from movies where movieType = @type
```

Is there a way to pass parameters at runtime  to the sql datasource?

Thanks

Comment: Also related to the question : The Select method will return an IEnumerable list of data rows. So keep that in mind ... code happily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add the parameter to your SqlCommand when you make your SQL call.

```
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", type);
```

In this example, the variable you are passing in from .Net is 'type'

This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx) should help you understand parameter passing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about [SqlDataSource control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dz12d98w%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), yes you can use SQL queries and statements that use parameters.

For example:

```
var source = new SqlDataSource(myConnectionString, 
     "SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE ColName = @M);
source.SelectParameters.Add("@M", DbType.Int32, ddl.SelectedValue);
```

MSDN has [good article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z72eefad%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with [SelectParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z72eefad%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in the markup or codebehind

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource
      id="SqlDataSource1"
      runat="server"
      DataSourceMode="DataReader"
      ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnection %>"
      SelectCommand="select * from movies where movieType = @type">

       <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter name="type" ControlID="MyDropdownList" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
       </SelectParameters>
  </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

[More on ControlParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.controlparameter%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)